# Synchornizing contents of databases

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization

My problem: I have many branches, each having its own database. However, their databases structure is the same, only data in each branch differ. Because clients need to know data of each other, I have too a "master" or "central" database in a server, whose job is to help client databases to synchronize contents of each other, by storing all changes happening in client databases.

You may ask "why don't you have a single database in the server that client connect to it directly, rather than having duplicate copies of client databases?". The answer is, client machines have not always-available connection to the server. Because internet connection may be broken sometimes, I need to store changes locally then synchronize with server when connection is available. After that, clients connect to server to maintain the latest data.

I need some solution to track all changes happened locally. Is the above design feasible? Is there a better\easier solution? If it is suitable, how can I perform the job of synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx). The topic is vast and you will need to spend several days reading before deciding on the proper solution. You have to decide your replication strategy ([Transactional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx) or [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx)), your topology and various other replication aspects like [vertical and horizontal partitioning](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/horizontal-and-vertical-partitioning-in-replication). It may be something as simple as a publisher DB at the headquarters with merge subscribers at each branch.

Do not try to reinvent the wheel. There are many, incredibly dangerous, dragons under that bridge.